# Arduino loosing serial Bytes after READ

Tags: serial-port, arduino

I am having a trouble, i have a small gaming machine that has a Serial communication, i have to send a hex value so it can responde with a Hex value, where inside this hex value there is a number that i need to extract.

With a client that i have writen in c# it works perfectly i get every single byte,

But with arduino i get this: 
'00 03 03 12'
where i normaly should get this: '01 10 00 03 43 20 03 12' , you see that i loose half of the bytes.

i tryed everything and i dont get arround it.

When i communicate with the arduino and the Pc everything reads and writes perfect. but with the Gaming Machine only sending works good but when i receive data i loose it like above.
Thank you

here is the code:

```
void setup()
{
  Serial3.begin(19200, SERIAL_8E1);
  Serial.begin(19200, SERIAL_8E1);
  delay(1000);
}

void statsP()
{ 
  delay(400);
  Serial3.write(0x01);
  Serial3.write(0x10);
  delay(300);
}

void generalpol()
{
  delay(200);
  Serial3.write(0x80); 
  Serial3.write(0x81);
}

void loop() 
{
  generalpol();
  statsP();
  if(Serial3.available()){
    char commandbuffer;
    int j = Serial3.available();
    for (int i =0 ; i<j ; i++)
    {
      while( Serial3.available()) {
        commandbuffer = Serial3.read();
        Serial.write(commandbuffer); 
      }     
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try:

```
char commandbuffer;

while(Serial3.available() > 0){
    commandbuffer = Serial3.read();
    Serial.write(commandbuffer,HEX);
}
```

However you need make sure you have received all the characters before you go back to the beginning of the loop() routine and start transmitting characters. Because the characters come into the Arduino very slow compared to how fast the while loop will execute.  Is 12 always the last character or is it always 8 characters?

If 12 is always the last char I would add:

```
while (commandbuffer != 12){
    while(Serial3.available() > 0){
        commandbuffer = Serial3.read();
        Serial.write(commandbuffer,HEX);
    }
}
```

Of course, now you need to add a timeout in case the 12 never comes, I leave that as an exercise for you.

Answer (score 0):

I will try this (instead part after generalpol() and statsP()) :

```
char commandbuffer;
if(Serial3.available() > 0){
   commandbuffer = Serial3.read();
   Serial.write(commandbuffer,HEX);
}
```

I think that you only need to detect "something" in receive buffer of Serial3 , read it (which mean, move that byte from buffer, too), and send like byte (in HEX form) to Serial.
I hope that delays which you put in your functions generalpol() and statsP() are ok

Answer (score 0):

thank you for ur suggestions i found the problem it was at the Serial configuration, since windows handles some configuration automatically, in arduino you have to configure it manually like WakeUp bits, so i hmchanges the konfig to Parity Non and Stop bits 2, now it works great thanks again